# How to destroy context pointers in QML?

Tags: qt, pointers, qml, qtquick2

I instantiated dynamically an object in main() and set it on context like:

```
 Controller *controller = new Controller();
 engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("controller", controller);
```

After this point I don't have access to the pointer in c++ only in QML. At the end of the application I want to release the pointer (more specific in `Component.onDestruction`). I couldn't figured out how to do it in QML.

1. I tried `controller.destroy()` but it returns : `Error: Invalid attempt to destroy() an indestructible object`.
2. Also tried `controller.deleteLater()` but it gave me: `TypeError: Property 'deleteLater' of object Controller(0x4914028) is not a function`.
3. `delete controller` does nothing.

I've searched the documentation but couldn't found what I was looking for. Anyone has any idea? Thanks!

Comment: Please read [this](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-data.html#data-ownership) and [this](https://wiki.qt.io/Shared_Pointers_and_QML_Ownership) links.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use a smart pointer so that it gets destroyed when it goes out of scope.

```
//main.cpp

QSharedPointer<Controller> controller =
    QSharedPointer<Controller>(new Controller(), &QObject::deleteLater);
engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("controller", controller);
```